# why so slow this mysql query to execute?

Tags: mysql

```
select 
    'Owner' as 'Type',
    count(s.shipwynum) as Total,
    o.ownwynum as WYNum,
    o.ownshortnam as 'Short name',
    o.ownnam as 'Full name',
    cio.weburl as 'Web URL',
    count(if(s.statuscod = 'O',1,null)) as 'number of orders',
    count(if(s.statuscod = 'S',1,null)) as 'number of ships' 
from owner o 
left join ship s on o.ownwynum = s.benownwynum and s.deleted = 'N' and
      s.statuscod in ('O','S') and
      s.benownwynum != '' and s.benownwynum !='0' and s.benownwynum is not null 
left join companyinfo cio on cio.objwynum = s.benownwynum and
      cio.deleted = 'N' and cio.comflag = 'OW' where o.deleted = 'N'     
group by o.ownnam
```

This query runs under at 9 minutes and 55 seconds and retrieve 10,106 records.

My question is why it takes a lot of time to fetch the data and what are the issues to less its time for execution ?

But interesting thing is that I have run this query :=

```
select * from ship
```

It takes 3 minutes and 12 seconds under execution and will fetch 75,672 records.

Any idea to optimize it ?

Comment: set an index on the key?:D

Comment: +1, Best answer you will get without seeing the full table definitions.

Comment: Please post the tables DDLs (the `CREATE TABLE` statements), and the `EXPLAIN` plan. Then others will be able to see where the bottlenecks are and which indexes are missing.

Comment: From the information of the post, I can suggest to change the 'deleted' column to a boolean datatype, this is more optimal then a char.

Comment: Just to clarify... you are doing LEFT JOINs from owner to ship and company information... Is your intent to have EVERY OWNER ( where deleted = 'N' ) regardless of shipments? Or are you more concerned with shipments and who the owner it was associated with. Additionally, from your query, having an index on "deleted" will help optimize the query at the outer level.  Additionally and index on the ship table for benownwynum.

Comment: deleted column is enum datatype

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless you are really meaning to avoid null values of s.shipwynum, try this - replace:

```
count(s.shipwynum) as Total
```

with

```
count(*) as Total
```

It is generally true that COUNT(*) operates faster than COUNT(expression).

---

Another experiment, replace:

```
count(if(s.statuscod = 'O',1,null)) as 'number of orders'
count(if(s.statuscod = 'S',1,null)) as 'number of ships'
```

with

```
sum(if(s.statuscod = 'O',1,0)) as 'number of orders'
sum(if(s.statuscod = 'S',1,0)) as 'number of ships'
```

Comment: When u replace 0 at null then it will retrieve values as total(orders+ships)

Comment: @Jessica: Was "sum" also used in place of "count"?